# Copy files from a zip archive to another without uncompressing them

Tags: c#, zip

Is there any C#-accessible library that I can use to copy a compressed file from a zip archive to another without going through the round-trip of uncompressing and re-compressing the file?

Last time I tried SharpZipLib, I couldn't find a way to access the compressed data that didn't "helpfully" uncompress it first.

Comment: If you want copy, Enter ZIP file then use [file.copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-8.0) ! ... if you need some of its content, then I believe that you have to uncompressed it.

Comment: If the data in the zip archive is compressed (which it is most of the time), then how should it be possible to copy it without decompressing it first? The data in the raw form does not exist anymore after compression has been applied so there is no way you can copy data in the raw form. Also - you do not need to recompress anything if you just want to extract data from an archive or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Are you worried about the performance of it, or the fact you need to write code to do this extra recompression?

Comment: @Charlieface the performance. All libraries I know of will "helpfully" do the extra recompression.

Comment: @MarkusSafar I want to move data around between archives. Create a new archive with some files (but not all) from the old one, some new files (which I *would* compress when adding them), etc. Since ZIP archives are not "solid" archives, any compressed file within it is still a single self-contained entity. I am aware that what I want to do would not be possible with a "solid" archive.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a utility, [zipknit](https://zlib.net/zipknit16.tar.gz), in C that will support that you are trying to do. You can compile it and run it from your C# program, or you can try to adapt the code to use directly in your application.

zipknit takes a list of zip files and writes out one zip file with the contents of all of those, without decompressing and recompressing the entries:

```
zipknit archive1.zip archive2.zip archive3.zip > totalarchive.zip
```

(Read the caveats in the source code comments about the case where entries with the same file name exist in more than one of the input zip files.)

If you want to copy just one zip entry from a zip file that has other stuff in it, you would first need to make a zip file with only that entry. Copy it to a temporary zip file and delete the other entries. That leaves the one entry untouched, as well as not decompressed and recompressed. Then use zipknit with the resulting one-entry zip file. Or you could modify the zipknit.c code to select entires to knit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) library for this task.

Suppose you have two zip files:

- Input.zip containing files a.docx, b.docx
- Output.zip containing file c.docx

If you want to copy the a.docx file from Input.zip to Output.zip, you can use the following this code (.NET 6):

```
using System.Text;
using Ionic.Zip;

using var input = new ZipInputStream("data\\Input.zip");
using var output = new ZipOutputStream("data\\Output.zip");

while (input.GetNextEntry() is { } entry) 
{
    if (entry.FileName != "a.docx")
    {
        continue;
    }
    
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    int size;
    output.PutNextEntry(entry.FileName);
    while ((size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, size);
    }
}
```

If you encounter encoding-related errors, you may need to install the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages package. After installing the package, register it in your application by adding the following code:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

I hope this solution can help you.

Comment: I think that still uncompresses and recompresses. And you can do the same thing using the builtin `ZipArchive` class. Also why a read loop, and not just use `CopyTo`?

Comment: I know that in SharpZipLib at least, such code would uncompress and decompress the data. I suspect it's the same for DotNetZip, because it's "intuitive" code for uncompressing, and I don't see any extra option in this code to say "today we're manipulating the compressed data directly instead of doing the usual thing".